# maxScrollV reporting incorrectly

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an html text field that displays content from an xml file, and a class that determines whether or not to show a scrollbar.

The code that determines this is as straightforward as

```
if (field.maxScrollV>1){
  showscrollbars()
}
```

And 9 times out of ten it is working. Sometimes - it seems when the html contains `<li>` - maxScrollV is reporting '2' and the scrollbars are showing, even though all text is visible onscreen and it will not actually scroll at all.

Even if I force the textfield larger: field.height +=100 it still reports maxScrollV=2 and shows the scrollbars.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if I add a small timer delay it will report the value correctly. I imagine this means I need to look as the `addedToStage` event?

Comment: I read that if you call textfield.getCharBoundaries(0), it forces it to recompute its boundaries correctly right away.  Also a related problem is that a non-zero TextFormat "leading" value ("line spacing" in Flash IDE) will cause maxScrollV's value to be one greater than it should.  The maxScrollV calculation seems to include an extra leading value at the end, so even though the condition "textHeight <= (height - 4)" is true, maxScrollV thinks the height of the contained text is a little longer. Your problem can be solved by not showing a scroll bar as long as "textHeight <= (height - 4)".

Answer (score 0):

You have said it yourself if maxScrollV is 2 then the bars get shown, so the question is why sometimes does this happen ? 
Take latency out of the equation for a test on enterframe set the scroll bar continually (obviously no good in production !!!) then see if it works.

This will mean that its not a latency issue (anytime you get 9 times out of 10 latency is often the issue as its indeterminate when something isnt happening)

also try online which should make it worse !

Comment: Yeah, the question is "why does maxScrollV report 2 on a field that doesn't scroll"

Comment: It may not recompute the dimensions right away when height is changed, although I think it does when the text is changed, so you'd want to change that last.  Alternatively, it seems to update it's values if you call textfield.getCharBoundaries or textfield.getLineMetrics.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used to resize a TextField to be big enough to fit the text without scrolling.

```
var metrics:TextLineMetrics = getLineMetrics( numLines - 1 ); //get metrics of last line of text
var minimum_height = metrics.height + metrics.leading; //include one extra leading in all textHeight measurements to avoid undercalculating the textHeight (maxScrollV seems to use a value for textHeight that includes an extra leading value)
var real_textHeight:Number = textHeight + metrics.leading;  //include one extra leading in all textHeight measurements to avoid undercalculating the textHeight (maxScrollV seems to use a value for textHeight that includes an extra leading value)
var gutter:Number = 4; //2px top and 2px bottom gutter exists on all textfields
height = (h < minimum_height) ? (minimum_height + gutter) : (real_textHeight + gutter); //match height of text, ensuring height is at least enough to display one line, even if there is no text.  also accounts for 4 pixel gutter and extra leading value that would otherwise throw off maxScrollV
```

In your case, you're not trying to resize the textField, but in principle to determine whether to display scrollbars, you'd want to use:

`var needsScrollBars:Boolean = ((textfield.textHeight + metrics.leading) > (height + 4));`

The key is to include that extra leading value, which is not inluded in the textHeight property, but seems to be taken into account by maxScrollV.  The issue with maxScrollV being one too many goes away if leading is zero.

If your issue is a delay in the fields being updated, then make sure you are setting the "text" property last.  If you're performing auto sizing, you can either change the height and then reset textfield.text or call either textfield.getCharBoundaries or textfield.getLineMetrics, which seem to force it to update its internal values.

Finally, another issue I noticed is that numLines is wrong initially.  For example, a blank text field on the stage will report numLines = 2.  Once "text" is set at runtime, this value corrects itself, so if you just set `text = ""`, then numLines is correct.  In any case, textHeight + leading is a good "real" value to use for the height of the text, and as always "required height of text field to avoid scrolling" should be "real text height" + 4.